# List files on remote server

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run the following command:

```
ssh -A -t -i ~/.ssh/DevKP.pem -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@MyServer "for file in  \`ls /root/spark/work/ \`; do  echo 'file - ' $file;  done"
```

The output is:

```
file - 
file - 
Connection to MyServer closed.
```

When I ran the command on the remote server itself:

```
for file in  `ls /root/spark/work/ `; do  echo 'file - ' $file;  done
```

I get the output:

```
file -  test1.txt
file -  test2.txt
```

How do I get ti to work on the local server? it seems that it gets the right files (because there were two sysouts)

anyone has any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `$` in `$file` to make sure the remote shell interprets it instead of your local. You should also simplify the `ls /root/..` to `for file in /root/../*`:

```
ssh root@MyServer "for file in /root/spark/work/* ; do  echo 'file - ' \$file;  done"
```